# ClassLoader [com.bea.wls.redef.RedefiningClassLoader] does NOT provide an 'addTransformer(ClassFileTransformer)' method

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, weblogic-10.x

When i am trying to deploy exploded directory with `fast-swap` enabled mode true in weblogic.xml on to weblogic 10.3 i am getting the following exception

```
<Apr 27, 2013 10:09:52 PM EDT> <Warning> <HTTP> <BEA-101162> <User defined listener org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.context.weaving.AspectJWeavingEnabler#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loadTimeWeaver': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: ClassLoader [com.bea.wls.redef.RedefiningClassLoader] does NOT provide an 'addTransformer(ClassFileTransformer)' method. Specify a custom LoadTimeWeaver or start your Java virtual machine with Spring's agent: -javaagent:spring-agent.jar.
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.context.weaving.AspectJWeavingEnabler#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loadTimeWeaver': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: ClassLoader [com.bea.wls.redef.RedefiningClassLoader] does NOT provide an 'addTransformer(ClassFileTransformer)' method. Specify a custom LoadTimeWeaver or start your Java virtual machine with Spring's agent: -javaagent:spring-agent.jar
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:480)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loadTimeWeaver': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: ClassLoader [com.bea.wls.redef.RedefiningClassLoader] does NOT provide an 'addTransformer(ClassFileTransformer)' method. Specify a custom LoadTimeWeaver or start your Java virtual machine with Spring's agent: -javaagent:spring-agent.jar
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:480)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ClassLoader [com.bea.wls.redef.RedefiningClassLoader] does NOT provide an 'addTransformer(ClassFileTransformer)' method. Specify a custom LoadTimeWeaver or start your Java virtual machine with Spring's agent: -javaagent:spring-agent.jar
    at org.springframework.context.weaving.DefaultContextLoadTimeWeaver.setBeanClassLoader(DefaultContextLoadTimeWeaver.java:82)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> 
<Apr 27, 2013 10:09:52 PM EDT> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID '1367114948992' for task '11'. Error is: 'weblogic.application.ModuleException: '
weblogic.application.ModuleException: 
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1373)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:468)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:204)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:37)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:60)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ClassLoader [com.bea.wls.redef.RedefiningClassLoader] does NOT provide an 'addTransformer(ClassFileTransformer)' method. Specify a custom LoadTimeWeaver or start your Java virtual machine with Spring's agent: -javaagent:spring-agent.jar
    at org.springframework.context.weaving.DefaultContextLoadTimeWeaver.setBeanClassLoader(DefaultContextLoadTimeWeaver.java:82)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> 
<Apr 27, 2013 10:09:52 PM EDT> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149202> <Encountered an exception while attempting to commit the 1 task for the application 'PDC_1306'.> 
<Apr 27, 2013 10:09:52 PM EDT> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149004> <Failures were detected while initiating deploy task for application 'PDC_1306'.> 
<Apr 27, 2013 10:09:52 PM EDT> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149078> <Stack trace for message 149004
weblogic.application.ModuleException: 
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1373)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:468)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:204)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:37)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:60)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ClassLoader [com.bea.wls.redef.RedefiningClassLoader] does NOT provide an 'addTransformer(ClassFileTransformer)' method. Specify a custom LoadTimeWeaver or start your Java virtual machine with Spring's agent: -javaagent:spring-agent.jar
    at org.springframework.context.weaving.DefaultContextLoadTimeWeaver.setBeanClassLoader(DefaultContextLoadTimeWeaver.java:82)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
```

if i remove

```
 <fast-swap>
       <enabled>true</enabled>
    </fast-swap>
```

from weblogic.xml ,application deploying successfully .

is there any workaround for this ?

Answer (score 0):

What were the changes to the classes you dropped that caused this issue ?

see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/deployment/deployunits.html#wp1053872 . theres a table below that shows what changes are NOT supported by fast-swap. If your chnage was not supported it could be resulting in the error you see.

Comment: my application is not even deployed with fast-swap enabled .